# How can I tell Git to use a different gitignore file than ".gitignore"?

Tags: git, gitignore

I can tell Git where the Git repository is with `--git-dir`. I can tell Git where the working tree is with `--work-tree`. How do I tell Git where the gitignore file is?

Q. Why would I want to do such a thing?

A. For some working trees I have two different Git repositories. One is in the standard location of `.git`. This repository I use for normal version control. The other respository is in `.git.sync`. This repository I use for periodic automatic syncing between computers. I.e., it's my own little Dropbox clone implemented with Git and a little script that runs periodically.

Ideally, I would be able to tell Git to use `.gitignore.sync` for the `.git.sync` repository, rather than having Git use the very same `.gitignore` that it uses for normal version control.

Q. Why don't I just use Dropbox?

A. It doesn't sync symlinks. Bad Dropbox!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `core.excludesfile` to specify the new ignore file. By default this will only affect the current repository; you can use the `--global` option if you want to change the default value.

```
git config core.excludesfile ".new_gitignore"
```

**Edit 1**

AFAIK, `.gitignore` cannot be *disabled*. And it takes precedence over `.git/info/excludes` and `core.excludesfile`. The only way I can think of is having some hacks using filters. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/326543) explains the use of filters well.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently this allows you to specify a third gitignore file, in addition to `.gitignore` and `.git.sync/info/exclude`. I also need to be able to ***turn off*** `.gitignore`, since the directory may have a `.gitignore` that is not within my ability to control.

Comment: @Douglas, have some edits based on your comment. AFAIK there is no way to turn off .gitignore.

Comment: @Srinkanth, thanks for the update! I'm having a hard time figuring out,  though, how the filter mechanism could be used to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Each repository has an `info/exclude` file - there should be one in `.git/info/exclude` and in `.git.sync/info/exclude`.  Populate those exclude files just as you would `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think that would *always* work for me, though, unless I can tell Git also to not also use `.gitignore`. For projects that I work on with other people, I'm not always free to get rid of `.gitingore`.

Answer (score 1):

".gitignore" seems to be hard-coded as a per-directory exclude file in git in most commands, taking precedence over all other ignore files.

However, I created a small patch for Git to overcome this limitation: https://gist.github.com/rev22/9954517

It adds the following configuration option:

**core.ignoreperdir**: Specify an alternative to '.gitignore' as a per-directory
exclude-file. If this is not set, the default '.gitignore' is used.
If this is empty, no per-directory exclude file is used.